# Testing mobile web application for accessibility

Tags: accessibility

Can anyone please let me know,

What kind of industry practices do exist to test mobile web application in an accessibility perspective?

Is the accessibility of a web application with mobile devices a requisit for conformance with common accessibility standards?

Thanks & Regards,
Renjith

Answer (score 2):

Yes, WCAG is technology agnostic and can be applied to any kind of technology.

The W3C has made a guide [Mobile Accessibility: How WCAG 2.0 and Other W3C/WAI Guidelines Apply to Mobile](https://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-accessibility-mapping/)